# SQL Server join with no common columns

Tags: sql-server, join

I need a help with below scenario

Table A is a hierarchy table. Table B is a transaction table. I need to alter the table b to bring the deptdesc, classdesc,subclassdesc from table A. How should I join the two tables in this scenario to get the respective description fields in table b as shown in result. Appreciate your help

**Table A**:

```
DeptID ClassID SubClassID DeptDesc ClassDesc SubClassDesc
001    001     001        Math     A         A1
001    001     002        Math     A         A2
001    002     001        Math     B         B1
002    001     001        Eng      A         A1        
002    002     001        Eng      B         B1
002    002     002        Eng      B         B2
```

**Table B**

```
 deptid Classid subclassid updatedate Status
 001    002     002        01-Mar-16  Yes
 002    001     001        02-may-16  No`
```

Table B results

```
 deptid Classid subclassid updatedate Status Deptdesc  ClassDesc Subclassdesc
  001    002     002        01-Mar-16  Yes    Math      B         B1
  002    001     001        02-may-16  No     Eng       A         A1`
```

Comment: `Table A` is not normalized

Comment: Is your example correct? How does `001 002 002` get you `Math B B2` when there is no such entry in table a?

Comment: sorry , you are correct, i have edited the question, thx

Comment: Isn't this just a join on deptid, classid and subclassid?

Comment: There is still no entry in Table A that matches `001 002 002`..

Answer (score 1):

With `Inner Join`

```
SELECT TableB.deptID, TableA.ClassID, TableB.subClassID, updatedate, Status, DeptDesc, 
ClassDesc, SubClassDesc FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableA
ON TableA.DeptId = TableB.deptId 
AND TableA.ClassId = TableB.classId 
AND TableA.SubclassId = TableB.subclassId
```

you will have the result:

```
Table B Result
deptid Classid subclassid updatedate Status Deptdesc  ClassDesc Subclassdesc
  002    001     001        02-may-16  No     Eng       A         A1
```

With `Left Join` instead of `Inner Join` you should have as result:

```
Table B Result
deptid Classid subclassid updatedate Status Deptdesc  ClassDesc Subclassdesc
  001    NULL    002        01-Mar-16  Yes    NULL      NULL      NULL
  002    001     001        02-may-16  No     Eng       A         A1
```

But you can not have:

```
Table B Result
deptid Classid subclassid updatedate Status Deptdesc  ClassDesc Subclassdesc
  001    002     002        01-Mar-16  Yes    Math      B         B1
  002    001     001        02-may-16  No     Eng       A         A1
```

because you do not have `DeptId = 1, ClassId = 2, SubClassId = 2 in TableA.`